# VirtualBox failed to import OVA

Tags: windows-vista, virtualbox, virtual-machine, troubleshooting

On a fresh (re)install of VirtualBox 4.2.13 running on a Windows Vista host machine, I go to File > Import Appliance, and grab [an OVA file that I downloaded](http://boxen.math.washington.edu/home/sagemath/sage-mirror/win/index.html). I am given the following super helpful error message:

> Failed to import appliance C:\Users\ibm\Desktop\sage-5.9.ova.

And no error log anywhere that I can see. I have absolutely no VMs running or loaded or created in VirtualBox, this is a fresh install. Apparantly there are some issues with renaming your OVA files, but this one hasn't been renamed. I found some other scattered, idiosyncratic issues reported on Google, but none of them seem to apply to my case.

[This thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=54463) seems to suggest that some OVAs only work with certain versions or brands of VM software? If that's the case, how would I tell which one to use? (the site I downloaded the OVA from recommended VirtualBox specifically)

Please note this is my first ever time using any VM software.

Overall, **what is the proper troubleshooting procedure here?**

Comment: OVA files are TAR files. Try to unpack the TAR and open the OVF file inside, which is a plain text file with the VM configuration

Comment: @golimar Are you sure? 7-Zip says it's unable to open it, but it can normally open TARs just fine.

Comment: Embarassingly, I just realized my OVAs md5 doesn't check against the one on the site. The server is down right now so I'll have to wait a bit to download it.

Comment: Confirmed. Bad download, sorry about that. Literally the first time that's ever happened to me.